# How to change/reset zoom in CodeBlocks?

Tags: code-blocks

I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Capslock</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> 4-5 times. Each time the font-size of the editor shrunk. I checked Settings -> Editor -> Font, but the problem was not from font-size, it's like a "zoom-out" thing. I tried `sudo apt-get remove codeblocks` and `sudo apt-get install codeblocks` but unfortunately it didn't reset the preferences. What can I do now?

Comment: While you cannot upload images yet, you can post links to them. If you find you cannot, leave off the leading `http://`. Then we can check them and edit them into your question for you.

Comment: Note to self: you cannot remove application preferences with `apt-get remove []`, you should do it with `apt-get purge []`

Comment: Even `apt-get purge` will only remove *systemwide* configuration files. If you need to remove user-specific preferences, you generally need to find and delete configuration files/directories in your home directory. (They usually start with a `.`, or reside in `.config`; to see them in Nautilus, press Ctrl+H or View > Show Hidden Files.) What does this have to do with the font size in Code::Blocks?

Comment: @EliahKagan One way that i tried to get sizes back to normal(As i explained in the question) was trying to remove code blocks preferences by removing and reinstalling the whole application, i did it in the wrong way by using `remove` instead of `purge`

Comment: I'm glad `purge` worked. It's strange that it did work though. Most of the time when an interface setting like this is changed, it's changed for individual users only, and not systemwide.

Comment: @EliahKagan actually it was only for my user not system wide, and the way i solved it was not through purge, but i learnt a thing or two about it ;) thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a zoom out shortcut. I was able to solve the problem by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and scrolling with the mouse wheel. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + **Scroll Up** to **Zoom Out** and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Scroll Down to **Zoom In**.

Comment: for reference, `scroll up` and `scroll down` mean mouse scroll.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but the answers are incomplete.

To reset your editor font size to normal you can use:

**Edit->Special commands->Zoom->Reset** from the menu,

or you can bind a shortcut for that (you need to have the `codeblocks-contrib`package installed):

**Settings->Editor->Keyboard Shortcuts** and set to what you want, mine is Ctrl+0 (zero) because that is a common shortcut for this.

Comment: This was quite helpful, for using a laptop where there is no scroll wheel.

Answer (score 0):

For Zoom in / out in Blocks IDE :   use
Ctrl + Roll Mouse Wheel